# What is the fastest way to scan a set of URLs in Python?

Tags: python, url, wsgi

I need to scan a given set of URLs and get the HTTP status codes like "200 OK" in Python. I'm currently using urllib to do this. Is there a faster way to do this?

### Python code

```
def get_status(url):
try:
    return urllib.urlopen(url).getcode()

except StandardError :
    return None
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is.

1. Use multiple threads all checking different URLs at the same time.
2. Use raw sockets implementing a simple HTTP request. As soon as you get the 200 response (or any other code) you close the connection, avoiding unnecessary transfer of data.

Comment: I can't practically use threads since i'm writing wsgi app.please let me know if i can use them without constructing a global object,to directly out put the result of the scan to a webpage.
I'm currently working on the 2nd method.

Answer (score 4):

Couple remarks I would make for faster happier status checking. The first tip would be to use the http `HEAD` method. This asks the server for just the http headers (including the status code) without having it also serve the body of the page.

Second urllib works but I would recommend using the wonderful [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html) library which provides a much nicer api for pretty much everything you would want to do with http.

Last I would use the [gevents](http://www.gevent.org/) library to enable you to download each header asynchronously, vastly speeding up the whole process.

Comment: I think the http HEAD method will do the job.And thanks for the info about other libs..I probably should have a look about gevents.

Comment: Sharp recommendation on using HEAD over GET. Smart.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to do it in parallel in a non-blocking way. Check out eventlet library here: http://eventlet.net/. You can just grab an example from the front page http://eventlet.net/#web-crawler-example.

Comment: As i can understand,the lib will lode the whole page before it gives the status code.is that correct?

Comment: The example, yes; but you can easily see what kind of change you have to make.

Comment: I'v look in to the documentation.think that may help.do you think the libb is available via easy_install?

Comment: Same front page says: `easy_install eventlet`.

Answer (score 2):

For speed, try using [GRequests](https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests) to check urls asynchronously (not one at a time).

### Code

```
import grequests

urls = [
    'http://www.heroku.com',
    'http://tablib.org',
    'http://httpbin.org',
    'http://python-requests.org',
    'http://kennethreitz.com'
]

rs = (grequests.get(u) for u in urls)
# For even faster status code checks, use the HEAD method instead of GET
# rs = (grequests.head(u) for u in urls)

for r in grequests.map(rs):
    print r.status_code, r.url
```

### Output

```
200 http://www.heroku.com/
200 http://tablib.org/
200 http://httpbin.org/
200 http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html
200 http://kennethreitz.com/
```

Comment: Is this lib available via easy_install?..i'm using openshift as the pass and i can't directly install any lib.

Comment: I would recommend using pip over easy_install locally. You can easily add dependencies to an openshift project: https://openshift.redhat.com/community/kb/kb-e1017-adding-dependencies-to-applications

Comment: thanx for the info.don't you know about any lib that would scan a given array of urls asynchronously? with out me tell to do it?

Comment: Sorry, no. Not that I know of.

Answer (score 0):

Use threading. Put your code in a Thread class, and store the results in a global object. Call a bunch of threads.

Comment: Yes i could use threading.but the problem is i'm using this function in a wsgi application to scan like 1000++ urls.if i use a global object to store the results.i have to wait untill the whole scan finished.and the web site i'm willing to write will give me a gateway time out.